# Manager report in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm using a function called Get-ADdirectReports which recursively grabs all users who report to a specific manager (includes other managers and their team members if the manager is responsible for multiple teams). I'm trying to return all AD users and see if they recursively report to the defined manager.

Code

```
$Manager = Get-ADdirectReports -SamAccountName "ManagerName" | Select SamAccountName
$Users = Get-AdUser -Filter * -Properties * | Select SamAccountName

Foreach ($User in $Users) { 
If ($User -Contains $Manager) {Write-Host $User reports to $Manager} 
Else
{$User doesn't report to $Manager}
}
```

Comment: This line $Users = Get-AdUser -Filter * -Properties * | Select SamAccountName literally removes all the properties except SamAccountNamefrom the AD objects that you are storing in the $Users array. Including the .Manager field.

Comment: Why would the user's username contains the manager's username?

Comment: More importantly why would a custom object (that is what $User is) contain an array (assuming Get-ADDirectReports returns more than one result)?

Comment: Basically you need to set down with this code and understand line by line exactly what it is doing.

Comment: I was trying to grab SamAccountName from both since $Manager and $Users both only output the SamAccountName. The logic was that If that one of the $Managers SamAccountNames matched the  $Users SamAccountName it would report $User reports to $Manager.

Comment: Why? What does Get-ADDirectReports actually do?

Comment: It gathers Name, SamAccountName, Email and Manager from each user reporting to the specified manager. http://www.lazywinadmin.com/2014/10/powershell-who-reports-to-whom-active.html. So for example, If you specify a VP it will grab all people who report up to him all the way down the line. I was just looking for some help. I know both variables contain a list of SamAccountNames, not a specific single value. Just having a hard time getting the comparison to work.

Comment: Your code says that both variables contain a list of object that have a SamaccountName property. That is not at all the same thing as a list of strings that are the SamAccountNames. That is the first thing that you need to understand. Second your comparison ***$User -Contains $Manager*** is asking the question "Does this variable (which is a single value) contain this array?" a single value can never contain an array.

Comment: Also, Get-ADdirectReports is literally using Get-AdUser to determine who is a direct report. So I'm super confused why you feel that you need to do this.

Comment: Sounds like I went around it the wrong way. I’m trying to query all users accounts in my Test AD to find out if they report up the ladder to a specific manager. For example if I had the SVP of engineering and two directors underneath him then 15 managers underneath them, Get-ADdirectreports gets all of them when if I just queried direct reports of the SVP I’d just get the 2 directors underneath him. I’m trying to figure out how I would get this done. Both those variables contain the information I need, I’m just trying to figure out how to compare them in PowerShell to get my desired result

Comment: So what example output would you want to see from this?

Comment: The desired output would be something like this

      Anna Kurich reports up to Maria Thompson
      Abe Roberto doesn't report up to Maria Thompson

Thank you for your help

Comment: So you want to provide a user ID then get back the top level manager for that person?

Comment: I want to provide a SamAccountName of a specific manager and query all AD users to find out if they report up to that specific manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this is not the most elegant and certainly not the fastest way to do this but it should do what you want.

```
function Get-ADTopLevelManager{
    param(
        $identity
    )
    $result = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    $manager = Get-ADUser $identity -Properties Manager
    $result.Add($manager) | Out-Null
    $managerDN = $manager.Manager
    while($manager -ne $null){
        $manager = $null
        $manager = Get-AdUser -Filter {DistinguishedName -eq $managerDN} -Properties Manager
        $managerDN = $manager.Manager
        if($manager.SamAccountName -eq $result[-1].SamAccountName){
            $manager = $null
        }else{
            $result.Add($manager) | Out-Null
        }

    }
    $result
}

$allUsers = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
foreach($adUser in Get-AdUser -Filter *){
  $temp = New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{'User' = $adUser.SamAccountName; 'Managers' = Get-ADTopLevelManager $adUser.SamAccountName}
  $allUsers.Add($temp) | Out-Null
}
```

So at this point you have a collection of objects that links any given user to all of their managers. So lets say you want to know what users have Manager1 in their chain of command anywhere:

```
$allUsers | Where-Object{$_.Managers -Contains Manager1}
```

Or if you want to know the immediate manager of user User1:

```
($allUsers | Where-Object{$_.User -eq User1}).Managers[0]
```

Or if you want to know the top level manager for User1:

```
($allUsers | Where-Object{$_.User -eq User1}).Managers[-1]
```

Comment: Oh, and you should probably make the name of that function be more accurate. I initially wrote it to just return the top level manager for a user then I saw your clarification comment.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but still worth trying I guess

```
function GetADUserManagerRecursive {
    param (
        $Identity
    )
    $UserAD = Get-ADUser $Identity -Properties Manager
    $DirectManager = $UserAD.Manager
    $DirectManager = Get-ADUser -Identity $DirectManager -Properties Manager
    Write-Output $DirectManager.DistinguishedName
    if ( $DirectManager.Manager -ne $UserAD.DistinguishedName ) {
        GetADUserManagerRecursive -Identity $DirectManager
    }
}
```

Once done, you may want to get all manangers of a specific user recursively, save it in variable and then check if a manager is there in the variable:

```
$managers = GetADUserManagerRecursive -Identity user
$managers = $managers | select -unique
(Get-ADUser bossname ).SamaccountName -match $managers.SamaccountName
```

PS Please note you might need changing `$DirectManager.Manager -ne $UserAD.DistinguishedName` to `$DirectManager.Manager -ne $null`.
I have seen companies where topmost boss has been a manager of himself